# winston howto modify the output order of timestamp, level, message etc

Tags: node.js, winston

I use `winston` for logging, here's my codes:

```
const { createLogger, format, transports } = require('winston')

const logger = createLogger({
  level: 'info',
  format: format.combine(
    format.timestamp({format: 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss'}),
    format.json()
  ),
  transports: [new transports.File({filename: 'logs/new_combined.log'})]
})

logger.info('haha')
```

The output is:

```
{"message":"haha","level":"info","timestamp":"2019-01-03T11:13:32"}
```

I want to adjust the output order to make `timestamp` ahead, then `level`, then `message`, as following:

```
{"timestamp":"2019-01-03T11:13:32","level":"info","message":"haha"}
```

How to do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's one way it can be done using `winston.format.printf`

```
format: format.combine(
    format.timestamp({format: 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss'}),
    format.printf(info => `${JSON.stringify({timestamp: info.timestamp, level: info.level, message: info.message})}`)
  )
```

Answer (score 4):

I was able to get this working using the following:

```
    format: winston.format.combine(
        winston.format.timestamp(),
        winston.format((info) => {
            const {
                requestId, timestamp, level, message, ...rest
            } = info;
            return {
                requestId, timestamp, level, message, ...rest,
            };
        })(),
        winston.format.json({ deterministic: false }),
    ),
```

This has the benefit of still using the safer stringify Winston uses that has circular reference protection.  In my case this is on an AWS Lambda so I put requestId first for easy reference.

Answer (score 0):

another solution which keeps all of your custom fields:

```
  format: format.combine(
        format.timestamp({format: () => new Date().toISOString()}),
        format.printf((info) => {
          const obj = {...info};

          delete obj.timestamp;
          delete obj.level;
          delete obj.message;

          return JSON.stringify({
            timestamp: info.timestamp,
            level: info.level,
            message: info.message,
            ...obj,
          });
        })
      ),
```